# Devise - Showing locked message before password message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, authentication, devise

I'm attempting to implement the lockable module in Devise. I want to set it up so that if an account is locked, it shows the locked message regardless of whether the password is correct or not. Importing lockable before database_authenticatable gives the desired behavior, as long as the number of attempts are higher than the max attempts, but there are other reasons why an account might be locked. I've overridden #unauthenticated_message so that it returns :locked when #access_locked? is true, but that didn't seem to do anything. Is there a way to make this happen?

It looks like Devise's standard behavior is not to reveal the locked status of an account unless the password is correct, as this thread argues: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/plataformatec-devise/8BWkoYf-uy8 So to head off requests to make me justify my reasoning, this seems wrong to me. In my mind, the whole point of locking the account is to avoid password enumeration. I don't really care if someone knows a particular email is registered on my site (especially since enumerating on the user creation page is possible anyway), but why give someone limitless attempts to guess a password? I'm open to being convinced, but it seems totally backwards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue. Only thing I could do is increase the number of attempts.
Eg: If I want to allow 3 login attempts, change

`config.maximum_attempts = 3` 
to 
`config.maximum_attempts = 4`

This way the account wont get locked if the user provides wrong password for 2 times and correct password at the third time. But this is not a good solution, although it solves my issue temporarily.